# Include a line hinting what to ask below the logo

Tags: feature-request

There is a long list of *Closed Questions* because the question was best suited for another Stack Exchange site.

When I open Stack Overflow, I don't see any description on what type of questions are expected in the site. Similarly there is often a confusion in other sites as well like Programmers, Server Fault and Super User.

I suggest you to include a line below the logo or somewhere on top hinting a new user as to what type of questions are expected.

Answer (score 11):

[image: Some freehand arrows and a freehand circle outlining the location of the FAQ buttong on the Stack Overflow interface.]

[image: More freehand circles and arrows outlining the location of the How To Ask box.]

Comment: Curses! I was beaten.

Comment: Ok. Don't need so many arrows to search around FAQ? Why a single line with 4-5 words can't be included? With FAQ there, you already close too many off-topics.

Comment: @Code1008: Because it is not explained in 4-5 words.

Comment: Those (superb) red arrows should be visible for one or two seconds when you first ask a question on SO (or as long as you ask question without having accepted an answer).

Comment: Actually I am trying to post suggested image but I'm not allowed till I gain 10 points overall.

Comment: @dystroy: Better wrap those elements in `<blink>`. ;P

Comment: @Code1008: You could post the link to it, and someone *might* inline it for you.

Answer (score 8):

Done:
[image]

---

---

Twice, even:

[image]

Comment: I like your bulls-eye-styled-freehand-circles.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to fill them in, even, but that was just not possible with a trackpad.

Comment: [Like this?](http://i.stack.imgur.com/1SPfh.png)

Comment: No, I was trying to fill them with scribbles.

Comment: Oh...well, I'm too lazy to do that. ;P

Comment: Looks like an earthquake centered on the *faq* - well done! ;)