# What about a post at the top for newbie's

Tags: feature-request

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Include a line hinting what to ask below the logo](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138379/include-a-line-hinting-what-to-ask-below-the-logo)

It seems like there's a ton of people on SO who don't understand what it is for, and then the community chastises them for screwing up by asking a bad question.

So what about a post/notification at the top, explaining how to use SO, that gets removed once you reach like 50 or 100 rep?

Comment: That's not a bad idea, however I'm afraid it's going to be yet another document people will somehow fail to read before asking. You know, just like the FAQ...

Comment: I [attempted something similar](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/111744/new-user-bad-question-tweak-push) but didn't get much traction then either. I think *something* is necessary.

Comment: All "newbies" have to read some stuff before they can post a question. And they have to tick the checkmark stating they have read it.

Comment: There's plenty of Just in Time help around SO; there are "hey, here's how to ask/answer" pages when you first try to post a question/answer, and IIRC, you're also directed to the FAQ

Comment: Yet more grey beard downvoting because they think new users should just "get it" (and they probably think new users 'deserve' a bit of chastising simply for being new users - "keeps 'em in line" or some such.) even though the SO interface is a poster child for bad/incoherent interface design. Ugh.

Answer (score 0):

This is just because people don't want to read out the documentation of [SOFAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/faq). I don't think that people will read it while SE has wrote down a good documentation for all network sites on their FAQ link.

While they have put the notification when you about to ask a question. And the same for a newbie when he/she click the <kbd>Answer</kbd> button to answer a question.

[image]

Then there should no problem at all to use SO or other SE network site for a newbie.

Comment: Down voter please care to comment what is wrong with it?

Comment: Hi avirk, I didn't downvote, but I suspect the vote might be because it's not clear what you're trying to say. The banner is already present, as evidenced by your screenshot. The last paragraph is very confusing, at least to me. Consider making an [edit] to clarify. Also, keep in mind that downvoting works differently on meta. It's possible the voter simply disagrees with you, and downvotes on meta mean "I disagree". Hope this helps! :)

Comment: @jmort253 I know about the downvote purpose that's why I need a little bit explanation although I have edited it as you suggested I think it would be more clear now.

Comment: **I** downvoted - the screenshot you posted is a good example of **BAD** GUI. It is a GUI designed by *programmers*. If you want people to "do the right thing" then you make it easy, clear. You don't arrogantly assert that they simply RTFM.

Comment: @skinnyTOD I don't think its arrogantly forced the newbie to live with it, just you have need to make give attention on that. If you are not giving attention on that **BIG** heading **How to Ask** then I don't think the newbie will try to notify in the notification area which is much smaller than it. However old notification method was good to notify as that was appear on the top of the site like a popup. But though newbie has a good interface to use the SE sites as they have clearly wrote down a good documentation that which kind of questions you should ask there.

Comment: @avirk: - your comment is mostly incoherent. Seems like you are just trashing new users like the "big boys" here and hope to get stupid "rep" points by emulating bullies. Very Bad Karma.

Comment: @skinnyTOD Not at all as sometime before I was also new user here and learned through that.