# Should StackOverflow be more proactive about teaching how to write a good question?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

Right now you can go to the new queue and it seems there's crap question after crap question, with the odd nugget of a good question buried among the drivel, and unfortunately I think this is devaluing the site.

I think we should take a more proactive approach in dealing with this.

For example, in the Question field, we could have a watermark overlay describing how to write a good question, and what not to write.

Otherwise, when a question is closed or put on hold we could automatically send the user an outline of how to write a good question.

Are there better ways to deal with this?

Comment: Related: [Include a line hinting what to ask below the logo](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/138379/include-a-line-hinting-what-to-ask-below-the-logo) ... Or the short version, we already have so much help all over the place, that everyone who "does not get it" won't get it with more help either.

Comment: Do you really think that people will bother reading such an overlay? In particular those who would ask bad questions? We already have people agree to asking good questions when they first sign up and that doesn't stop them.

Comment: @Oded, I hear you loud and clear and you're probably right - the type of user who doesn't bother to try to ask a decent question almost certainly won't bother reading up on how to do it. But if it's in their face every time they ask a question then *maybe* someone might get something from it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I have been a member of SO from the beginning and the site has evolved a lot - some for bad, some for good. If there is one thing that the Universe reliably is able to invent is more idiots. You can't fix stupid - no matter how hard you try. I believe the site and the community has gone above and beyond trying to teach people how to write good questions.

Comment: +1 for "you can't fix stupid"

Comment: +1 It's clear that at least _some_ managed to make it from their humble beginnings - it can't be _that_ hard, can it?

Answer (score 1):

It's not a bad idea, but don't forget: SO explains what questions are on-topic, and how to write a good questions, but if new users don't go to the Help center or to the FAQs on MSO, then it's their problem. Also, SO can't be sure that these members will actually *read* it, but it's worth a try.